# How do I find the oxidation number of a coordination complex

Tags: coordination-compounds, oxidation-state

I actually know how to calculate the oxidation number for coordination complexes but some complexes like the below are giving some reistance

$\ce{[Cu(NH3)_2][Fe(H2O)_3]}$ (diamminecopper(?) triaquoferrate(?))

I just wrote this example now and don't know wether it exists or not I am rather concerned about how do I find their oxidation numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it like this. Ammonia and Water are both neutral molecules, therefore they won't contribute to the charge of the two coordination spheres. There are also no subscripts, which indicates that iron and copper both have the same magnitude of charge. Now copper here could be +1 and iron could be in -1, or copper in +2 and iron in -2. (Of course, this isn't possible since this molecule doesn't exist.) I cannot conclusively say which though, without any further data, such as maybe their spin only angular momenta.

For other complex compounds, i suggest you practice, and eventually you'll get the hang of what oxidation states are common for different metals. Also use the concepts you use for normal covalent compounds. Trust me, it's very easy!