# Oxidation state of metals in complexes with bridging ligands

Tags: coordination-compounds, oxidation-state

How do I find the oxidation number of $\ce{Co}$ in a coordination complex like the 
tetraaminecobalt(2) $\mu$-amido $\mu$-oxo tetraamine cobalt(2) ion?

I searched all over the net but can't find it anywhere. Please help!

Comment: I meant oxidation number..sorry

Comment: Maybe this can help you. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22307/how-do-i-find-the-oxidation-number-of-a-coordination-complex?rq=1

Comment: But what should I consider as the oxidation states of oxo and amido ? @Anders MB ?

Comment: It’s no different from complexes with non-briding ligands.